# Polymorphic queries in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

by reading Hibernate Reference Guide, I came across:

14.8. Polymorphic queries

A query like:

```
from Cat as cat
```

returns instances not only of Cat, but also of subclasses like DomesticCat. Hibernate queries may name any Java class or interface in the from clause. The query will return instances of all persistent classes that extend that class or implement the interface. The following query would return all persistent objects:

```
from java.lang.Object o
```

The interface Named might be implemented by various persistent classes:

```
from Named n, Named m where n.name = m .name
```

Note that these last two queries will require more than one SQL SELECT . This means that the order
by clause does not correctly order the whole result set. (It also means you can't call these queries using
Query.scroll().)

So the question is, what will the last query return?

```
from Named n, Named m where n.name = m .name
```

it going to be an array of all object that implement "Named", all has the same "name" value, and since it's a "double request"

```
from Named n, Named m
```

does it mean the first half of the array will repeat itself in the second half?

Answer (score 0):

No it wont repeat itself in the second half, but there might be multiple instances of equal objects

```
select * from a,a
```

just computes the carthesian product a and a (i.e. all rows of a get joined with all rows of a) for example if table a contains only an id-column and has the values 1,2,3 the above mentioned query gives you the following

```
+-------------+
| a.id | b.id |
|-------------|
|  1   |  1   |
|  1   |  2   |
|  1   |  3   |
|  2   |  1   |
...
|  3   |  3   |
+-------------+
```

so

```
select id from a,a where a.id = b.id
```

returns

```
+------+
| a.id |
|------|
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  3   |
+------+
```

So your query will retiurn at least all objects implementing Named in your databse and possibly some duplicates if the same exists multiple times. With following database

```
+-------------+
| id   | name |
|-------------|
|  1   |  a   |
|  2   |  a   |
|  3   |  b   |
+-------------+
```

your query gives you

```
+----+------+----+------+
| id | name | id | name |
+----+------+----+------+
|  1 | a    |  1 | a    |
|  2 | a    |  1 | a    |
|  1 | a    |  2 | a    |
|  2 | a    |  2 | a    |
|  3 | b    |  3 | b    |
+----+------+----+------+
```

so since two entries have the same name the first gets joined with itself and with the other one and the same is true for the second one, which means if you have n objects with the same name hibernate will retrive each object n times.